# SQL Syntax error at line one - query is the same as a working one though?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'Order, Name, URL, UserName, Password, SiteName, Notes) VALUES ('','','','','','` at line 1

The sql is exactly the same as a working insert query; apart from the field/table names.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'USER', 'PASS','DATABASE');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$sql="INSERT INTO RemoteLinks (Order, Name, URL, UserName, Password, SiteName, Notes) VALUES('$_POST[Order]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[URL]','$_POST[UserName]','$_POST[Password]','$_POST[SiteName]','$_POST[Notes]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Not too sure why this isnt working as its working in a similar query. Thanks for any help, its appreciated.

Comment: $_POST[Notes] has some quotes and breaking it and BTW did u hear about SQL Injection ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***ORDER*** is a reserved word used in *order by* clause - surround with backticks "`"

**Update**

Here is a list of **[Reserved Words in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html)**.

You'd generally want to avoid using backticks to escape those reserved words, because backticks decrease portability of the code. So, you might need to learn those and use other words for column names, tables, databases, etc.

**IMPORTANT**

You should definitely use **[mysqli_prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)** and **[mysqli_stmt_bind_param()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)**!

Comment: bad suggestion to backtick all things.  A person learning the language will eventually run into the commonly known ones based on their table names and columns.  Once found, they probably wont forget on the next query.

Comment: @DRapp - fair enough. Updating with advice

Comment: `PASSWORD` is not reserved. At least that's what the link you provided says!

Comment: @ypercube - well, it's just a function and it seems to be safe using it. I've been overprotective here. 10x!

Comment: As the table is a blank table at this moment in time I changed the column names to save any future bother. Thanks to everyones posts on this though everything posted has been very helpful, still learning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use back ticks **`** for reserved colum names (Order) and Prepare SQL statement for execution and bind params to prevent sql injection:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO RemoteLinks (`Order`, Name, URL, UserName, Password, SiteName, Notes) '.
               'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insertQuery))
{
    $stmt->bind_param(
        "sssssss",
            $_POST['Order'],
            $_POST['Name'],
            $_POST['URL'],
            $_POST['UserName'],
            $_POST['Password'],
            $_POST['SiteName'],
            $_POST['Notes']);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: I wonder, where did you both get that password is a reserved word? (because it isn't...)

Comment: @ypercube - what blue said. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html I thought using mysql function name in query without back ticks might cause the query to fail.

Comment: OK, I was just wondering. But no, mysql is  quite "friendly". It distinguishes functions from other names by examining whether there is a parenthesis just after the function name. And it even throws an error is you have a space in between. `COUNT (something)` for example will throw an error in mysql!